# Codeigniter ActiveRecord update SQL error

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am working on CI 2.1.3 and encountering the following problem. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any reading or knowledge I need to do or know.

#### Codeigniter ActiveReocrd Update syntax

```
$data['spun'] = TRUE;
$this->db->update('registered', $data, 
                  "registered_id = $registration['registered_id']");
```

#### what I expected

```
UPDATE `registered` SET `spun` = 1 WHERE `registered_id` = 1
```

#### what CI generated

```
UPDATE `registered` SET `spun` = 1 WHERE `id` = 1
```

#### DB table (in bracketing notation)

registered(**registered_id**, registered_name, ..., spun);

#### Edit 1

I also tried the following, but CI give the same SQL.

```
$this->db->update('registered', $data, 
                  array('registered_id' => $registration['registered_id']));
```

Comment: before inserting first echo $registration['registered_id'] for testing

Comment: `$registration['registered_id']` is set as `1`

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is very easy. You can simply do this:

```
$data['spun'] = TRUE;
$this->db->update('registered', $data, 
                        array('registered_id' => $registration['registered_id']);
```

Comment: I did try that also, same SQL is generated by CI.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense!!! Can you please have a fresh install of Codeigniter just to test. Now go just to the welcome controller at index and try to debug it there. If the problem still remains.... well then I don't know :) . If yes then it simply means that you are looking at a wrong query.

Comment: yes, it doesn't make any sense! Now I went with parameterized query to achieve what I want.    I will try to debug later as now I am quite near deadline of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Code Igniter documentation:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update

you should use:

```
$data['spun'] = TRUE;
$this->db->where('registered_id', $registration['registered_id']);
$this->db->update('registered', $data);
```

Comment: That same page also include both my first syntax and the syntax proposed by @web-johny. It still gives me same SQL.